# How to increase memory size of jpg file?

Tags: photoshop, jpeg

My jpg file size is 5 KB. How can I make it 15 KB file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please Go through these Link.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Imagesize.htm

Comment: IF you feel that answer has helped you .. please mark as correct.. that other can take help from this, Thanks

Comment: Really cool link, it works just like photoshop. When you save your file at that time you just need to specify the size of jpg file.

http://pixlr.com/editor/

This link solved my problem easily.

Answer (score 1):

JPEG is a compression algorithm, and hence its 5 KB. Save it as a 32-bit or higher Bitmap to get maximum size possible for that image. And your question has a lot of scope for improvement. Give context, reasons, and methods you already tried.

Comment: its a simple file which i want to upload on a website but that website says that file size should be between 10kb - 20kb

Comment: image file should be only in jpg. so please can you guide me how to do it or please provide me a link. thanks